# How to use negative margin without losing the width

Tags: html, css, margin

[image]

I got these settings.. The red is a image.

[image]

I used

```
 marging-left: -8px;
```

on the image so the left goes outside his parent div. But what my question is how to counter the gap on the right side. (at the arrow in the second picture).

Comment: give us html and some css, or make jsfiddle

Comment: increase width of 8 pixels, or if block element, do not give any width in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution is probably to not assign a `width` to the element. Then you can use a negative `margin-left` to achieve your effect.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fr6Af/2/) for an example...

I used a CSS triangle, but it should work with an image as well.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! Even a better solution than a image !!